# Two clipboards possible?

Tags: clipboard-manager

It seems like I have two clipboards in Ubuntu?

- Text piece one: copy/insert via mouse context menu
- Text piece two: copy/insert via ctrl+c / shift+insert

How comes and where are configuration options for this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on Linux you have two of them, with a slight correction to what you noticed:

- you have the PRIMARY selection: select something with the mouse, and you can paste it by pressing the middle button (or the left and right buttons at once)
- and there is the CLIPBOARD selection that is similar to the clipboard on Windows and mac, using the Copy (Crtl+C), Cut (Ctrl+X) and Paste (Ctrl+V) keyboard shortcuts or menu commands (note that in a terminal, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V have other meaning, so you have to press Shift as well).

[Spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt)